# Check for updated package via yum in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, yum, dockerfile

In my Dockerfile I may have a step that looks like this in order to install some packages.

```
Run yum install pkg1 pkg2 -y &&\
yum -y clean all
```

The problem is that when I build the container more than once, Docker see's this command as not changing and never runs it. It instead chooses to use a previously cached layer.

However, pkg1 or pkg2 may have been updated in the yum repository and need to be updated, and since it instead used a cached docker layer, the container does not receive the updated packages.

I could build with the --no-cache option, but that would invalidate all cache layers, which substantially slows down the container build as usually my yum install commands are near the end of my Dockerfiles.

What is the best strategy to deal with this? Is there any solution to only invalidate the docker cache if there is a different version of the package in the cache vs repo?

Comment: what about running `yum clean expire-cache` before `yum install`?

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't help. The actual run command in the Dockerfile will still not have changed, so docker will think nothing has changed and continue to use its cached layer. Plus, I try to make sure that I always issue a `yum clean all` after a yum command(within same docker run), so there shouldn't be any yum cache present to be able to expire.

Comment: Create an image with all of the commands up until your `Run yum install pkg1 pkg2...` command.  Then, make a new Dockerfile that pulls `FROM` the image just created.  Run `docker build` with the `--no-cache` flag, which will only invalidate the latest cache layer.

Answer (score 0):

From "[Build cache](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#build-cache)", you could insert an `ADD` or `COPY` directive (of a dummy file) just before those `RUN` commands.

Whenever you want to invalidate the cache for the next `RUN`, modify the content of the dummy file, and the `ADD`/`COPY` (with the rest of the `Dockerfile` commands) won't rely on the cache.